# Evaluate integral $ I_s(x) \leq \frac{C}{(\pi(1-2 \alpha s))^{d/2}}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-2 \alpha s }|x|^2\right) $

Tags: integration, inequality

For all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n ,\hspace{5mm} 0  \leq s<t ,\hspace{5mm} t \in \mathbb{R}^+$ 
$$ I_s(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left|v\left(y \sqrt{2s}+x\right)\right|\exp(-|y|^2) \, \mathrm dy.  $$
How we can prove that $$ I_s(x) \leq  \frac{C}{(\pi(1-2 \alpha s))^{d/2}} \exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-2 \alpha s }|x|^2\right)  $$
if we have for all $ y \in \mathbb{R}^n ,|v(y) |<C\exp\bigl(\alpha |y|^2\bigr) $
such $C$ and $\alpha$ are constant $ ( C,\alpha > 0 ) $?

What I did:

Indeed, I think that the idea is to try to show 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}C\exp(\alpha |y \sqrt{2s}+x|^2-|y|^2)dy \leq \frac{C}{(\pi(1-2 \alpha s))^{\frac{d}{2}}}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-2 \alpha s }|x|^2\right)(\text{Gaussian integral =1 } ).$$

in fact we have $$ I_s(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left|v\left(y \sqrt{2s}+x\right)\right|\exp(-|y|^2) \, \mathrm dy.  $$ 
or we know that  for all $ y \in \mathbb{R}^n ,|v(y) |<C\exp\bigl(\alpha |y|^2\bigr) $
then
$$
I_s(x) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}C\exp(\alpha |y \sqrt{2s}+x|^2-|y|^2)dy
  \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}C\exp(|y|^2 2\alpha s+|x|^2-|y|^2)dy
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}C\exp(-(1-2\alpha s)|y|^2 +|x|^2)dy
$$
Let's make change variables by letting $ r=\sqrt{(1-2\alpha s)}y $ and $ dr=(1-2\alpha s)^{\frac{d}{2}} dy $
implies $$ I_s(x) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{C}{(1-2 \alpha s)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp(|x|^2)\exp(-|y|^2)dy$$

$$ I_s(x) \leq \frac{C}{(1-2 \alpha s)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp(|x|^2) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp(-|y|^2)dy$$

$$ I_s(x) \leq \frac{C}{(\pi (1-2 \alpha s))^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp(|x|^2) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{\pi}^{\frac{-d}{2}} \exp(-|y|^2)dy$$ 
I'll be grateful for any help especially for detailed one

Best regards, Educ .

Comment: Is $\alpha<0$? What is $t$? Should the integration variable be $y$ not $s$ in the first integral?

Comment: Where does the $s$ in $I_s(x)$ come from? The integral uses $s$ as the variable of integration. Perhaps you intended $\mathrm{d}y$?

Comment: Also should the square be on $y$ inside the bracket rather than outside in the argument of the exponential in the first integral?

Comment: yes you 're both right i 'll fixed now ,thanks for ur interest

Comment: I would suggest you need $\alpha<0$ or alternatively stick a $-$ sign in front of $\alpha$ where you define the bound on $v$ else the integral may not converge; and for that reason you may need to keep $\alpha$ in the integral that you are suggesting. $C$ must be positive by the bound on $v$, the exponential is positive and you don't need the absolute bracket round the integrand in the suggestion.

Comment: On the line right after "Indeed, I think that", the parentheses and absolute value signs are all mixed up so it's impossible to figure out what goes with what.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention i fixed it and i add some details

Comment: Hi, is there any suggestion ?? please

Comment: hi, is there anything about it

Comment: hi,  Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve that ?

Comment: the magic is where $d$ comes out and where you new variable $r$ goes?